# Добавление записей в input через checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить в один *input* данные с разных *checkbox*-ов.
Имеется два *checkbox*-а: один добавляет список машин из БД, а другой список цветов из БД.

Нужно, чтобы в *input* всё записывалось в виде `{id_cars_body:[21,22,32],id_colors:[1,4...]}`, где числа - это *id* машин и цветов в базе.

Сейчас код работает только с машинами. Как добавить ещё и цвета в эту конструкцию?

```js
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[class="bodys"]')),
  inp = document.querySelector("#spec");

inputs.forEach(function(c) {
  c.onclick = function() {
    var a = [];
    inputs.forEach(function(b) {
        b.checked && a.push(b.value)
      }
    );
    inp.value = "{id_cars_body:[" + a + "]}"
  }
});
```

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так

```js
var spec = {id_cars_body: [], id_cars_color : []};    

var bodys = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[class="bodys"]')),
    colors = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[class="colors"]'))
    inp = document.querySelector("#spec");

bodys.forEach(function (c) {
    c.onclick = function () {
        let a = [];
        bodys.forEach(b => b.checked && a.push(b.value));
        spec.id_cars_body = a;
        inp.value = JSON.stringify(spec);
    }
});

colors.forEach(function (c) {
    c.onclick = function () {
        let a = [];
        colors.forEach(b => b.checked && a.push(b.value));      
        spec.id_cars_color = a;
        inp.value = JSON.stringify(spec);
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо, то, что нужно! А как ещё можно убрать ковычки, которые создает JSON.stringify?

Comment: Не за что. Реализуйте форматер свой вместо JSON.stringify(spec); Я про100 на скорую руку